# MYSQL Select If Query - WP custom fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, forms

I am using a plugin that allows me to pull custom field values from the database to populate input fields. The plugin is a calculator form that adds up 3 custom fields that are each assigned to an input field using my original query.

Right now if I use this as my query it works fine --

```
SELECT meta_value AS value FROM tr_postmeta WHERE meta_key='pa_meta_debt' AND post_id=<%fieldname5%>
```

However if the custom field value is missing it throws off my calculations. How can do a select query to pull the value if present and if not give it a value of 0?

This is the query I was trying --

```
if (exists (SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tr_postmeta' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'pa_meta_debt'))
begin
    SELECT meta_value AS value FROM tr_postmeta WHERE meta_key='pa_meta_debt' AND post_id=<%fieldname5%>
end
```

It's not working though, how can I modify this?

Comment: Is meta_value numeric in this particular context? Do you expect to have 1 row or multiple rows returned with the above query?

Comment: Yes the meta value are all numeric. As far as rows Im not sure, Im not too familiar with MySql

Comment: If you run your query, how many rows does it return (in case there is a hit): 1 or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are numeric (or can be converted into numeric) **and** only 1 row can be returned by the query at most, then use `sum()` aggregate function with `ifnull()` or `coalesce()`. If you use `sum()`, then your resultset will always have 1 row. If no matching rows are found, then `sum()` will return null, which has to be converted into 0 using `ifnull()` or `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(meta_value),0) AS value
FROM tr_postmeta WHERE meta_key='pa_meta_debt' AND post_id=<%fieldname5%>
```

You also have the option of not changing your query and you either handle the no row returned status in the processing code, or you execute a

```
SELECT count(*) AS noofrows
FROM tr_postmeta WHERE meta_key='pa_meta_debt' AND post_id=<%fieldname5%>
```

query first, which will tell you if there are any matching records. I would use this latter approach if your query may return more than 1 rows.

Comment: Thanks. The first code I used and it works as needed. It didnt fix my problem with the plugin :( but it did answer my question and function correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
Select Coalesce((SELECT meta_value AS value FROM tr_postmeta WHERE meta_key='pa_meta_debt' AND post_id=<%fieldname5%> Limit 1),0)  As meta_value
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working. Currently the value in that field is 800,000 but as now it returns nothing using your code. Any ideas?

Comment: If the query does not return any rows, then coalesce() will not run. This is why I asked about the type of data and the number of rows.

Comment: Are you putting the query inside the if statement? If yes ten the select statement if the if was false. Use the code without the if statement.

Comment: The coalesce is checking the whole select statement it's not inside the select. So if no rows returns it will select the zero